# ht access 301 redirect domain.com/news/etc-etc to subdomain/news/etc-etc

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to use HT access to redirect a domain to a sub domain, but, as it is an archive site I am setting up, i only need to redirect all urls in a certain sub folder, not everything on the main domain.

so, any posts/pages/content in domain.com/news/etc-etc-etc need to be redirected to archive.domain.com/news/etc-etc-etc

does this look correct?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com\news\$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^archive.domain.com/news/
RewriteRule (.*) archive.domain.com/news/$1`

It is a wordpress installation, the reason for this is a whole new site is being developed, and the wordpress installation is being moved to a sub domain to act as an archive, so i don't want everything on the main domain.com to re-direct, as this will be where all the new content will be going.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem here?  Can you include an error message or statement of what is/isn't happening?

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `/news/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://archive.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```